# Is it possible to combine multiple documents using power query

Tags: excel, merge, powerquery

I want to combine documents from a folder which has identical documents that are added over time but for different months etc. I can combine them but I just get all the documents one below each other when I want all the numbers from each table added and summarised in one table.
Any ideas on how to do this ??

Comment: in powerquery, if they are stacked, click select the columns you want to preserve, right click ... group by ...  use the sum operation on each of the numerical columns

Comment: Look at using Group By with the desired aggregation. We can help further if you can update your question with an example of what you are trying to do.